# Find finite rings $(R, +, \times$) such that $(R,+)$ is cyclic.

Tags: ring-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, finite-rings

I'm finding finite rings $(R, +, \times$) such that $(R,+)$ is cyclic. $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is a good example.
Up to ring isomorphism, is there any exmaples other than $\mathbb{Z}_n$  ?

Thanks.

> For any finite cyclic group $(G,+)$, there exists $n$ such that
>   $(\mathbb{Z}_n, +)$ is isomorphic to $(G,+)$.

Edit: Thanks to those commenting this post. It disappoints me that the answer is NO.

Comment: No ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: If $R$ has a unit, then this unit is a generator. Indeed consider $\{k\cdot 1, k\in \mathbb{N}^*\}$, and let $k$ be minimum such that $k\cdot 1 = 0$. Then if $g$ is any element of $R$, $k\cdot g = k\cdot (1g) = (k\cdot 1)g = 0$, so since there is a generator $g$, we know that $(R,+)$ has at most $k$ elements, and so $1$ generates them. Therefore $R$ will be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}$ (there are some details I haven't checked but this seems right)

Comment: @Max Yes. If $R$ has a unit,  there exists $k$ such that $(R,+)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}$. Maybe I didn't express clearly. When I say isomorphisms, I mean ring isomorphism. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen could you please give more details?

Comment: I think Jyrki is right. Distributivity is tying your hands. Since the additive structure must be isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/k\mathbb Z$ use the additive group isomorphism to rename the elements. Then if you have $a\times b$ you always get $a\times b=(1+1+\dots 1)(b)=b+b+b\dots +b$ where the number of $+$'s is given by the integer that $a$ is sent to by the isomorphism, and so the $\times$ is fully determined by the $+$.

Comment: @DRF thanks. If $R$ has a unit namely $1$, then for any element $a$ of $R$, there exist $k$ such that $a=k\cdot 1$=$1+1+\cdots +1$. I find that $f(a)=k$ is a ring isomorphism from $R$ to $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ where $n$ is the order of $1$ in $(R,+)$. So Jyrki is right.

Comment: @zongxiang yi : I did mean ring isomorphism in my comment. What I was arguing was that of $(R,+)$ had a generator, then $1$ would be a generator, and once you have that, the fact that $R$ and $\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}$ are isomorphic (as rings) is quite simple (and you used that $1$ generates $R$ in your last comment : that's what I was proving)

Comment: @Max It looks great. How can I cite this result in a formal paper? I think it should be in some textbooks about finite ring. Can you give a reference for me. Citing this post is not preferred. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @zongxiang yi : I don't know of any references to it, though it must appear somewhere as you point out. If I don't find any references, I think the best would be either to leave it to the reader, or to prove it in an appendix. Though I think I found a paper that cites this result at some point, and he also proves the unicity . See my next comment for the reference

Comment: It's Benjamin Fine, "Classification of finite rings of order $p^2$", published in Mathematics Magazine, and it's Theorem 1 (according to him, it already appeared in Waterhouse, "Finite rings with cyclic additive groups" in American Mathematical Monthly). I think it's the fourth entry on Google if you type "classifcation of finite rings"

Comment: Thanks. @Max I read Benjamin Fine's paper. It's Theorem 1 says that for any $m$, there may be more than one cyclic ring with order $m$. Exactly the number of such different rings  is equal to the number of different divisors of $m$. To my inital question, is the answer yes? Because $\mathbb{Z}_m$ can be only isomorphic to one of  those rings.

Comment: As my answer states, $\mathbb{Z}_m$ is the only one if you ask that there be a unit (if you look at Benjamin Fine's paper, you see that the other rings don't have a unit). But if you don't require that there be a unit, then the answer is yes, and you can check my answer (or the paper) for a description of these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply to sum up the comments and answer the case where $R$ doesn't have a unit.

If $R$ has a unit, then $1$ must be a generator of $(R,+)$. Indeed, let $k$ be the smallest integer such that $k\cdot 1 = 0$. Then for all $g\in R$, $k\cdot g =0$, so that $|R| = k$, and thus since $\{0,...,k-1\} \to R$, $j\to j\cdot 1$ is injective (by minimality of $k$) it is also surjective (by equality of cardinals).

This way, $\phi : \mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z} \to R$ defined by $\phi(j) = j\cdot 1$ is well defined and a group isomorphism.

Moreover, $\phi(ab) = \phi(a\cdot b) = a\cdot \phi(b) = (a\cdot 1)\phi(b) = \phi(a)\phi(b)$ by distributivity, so $\phi$ is a ring isomorphism, which gives us the desired result.

However this does not hold if $R$ has no unit. Indeed there are finite cyclic rings with no unit, and they obviously cannot be isomorphic to rings with a unit (for instance, take $2\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ which is a ring (since it's an ideal) without a unit, since $2\times 2 =0$, and it's obviously cyclic (with generator $2$)). A question would be : what are the finite unitless rings with cyclic additive group ?

To answer this, let $(R,+,×)$ be such a ring, and let $a$ be a generator of $(R,+)$. $a^2 = p\cdot a $ for some $p\in \mathbb{N}$ (choose $p$ to be the smallest such for instance). Then take $m = p|R|$. 
We want to show that $R\simeq p\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$. Consider $\phi : R\to p\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ the  group isomorphism given by $\phi(a) = p$( well defined because $a$ generates $R$ and $p$ generates $p\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ and they have the same order).

Then $\phi(cd)= \phi((k\cdot a)(l\cdot a)) = \phi(kl\cdot a^2) = \phi(pkl\cdot a) = pkl p= pk pl = \phi(a)\phi(b)$, so that $\phi$ is actually a ring isomorphism.

Therefore the complete classifiction of finite rings with cyclic additive groups is : any such ring is isomorphic to one $p\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ with $p\mid m$. I haven't thought about the unicity of this representation (it is obviously unique in the unitary case, but what about the second case?)